# Teamviewer Free - feature not included in your plan ("Disable remote input and show black screen")

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, teamviewer

I occasionally need to connect to my work computer from home. I was using TeamViewer for a few years now. However, after latest update the "Disable remote input" and "Show black screen" are unavailable. I was cool with reconnecting every so often (thank you for using TV, this was a free session...). However, missing on those functions is a deal breaker. I've tried to rollback to older version, but it worked exactly once (and even if it worked, I still got the "not included in plan" message). Doesn't work since. And I've tried several older versions of TV 12. It seems it is linked to account rather.

I can't find any info on TV website what is this - a feature or a bug, I mean. TV free supposed to be not limited, but it clearly is. The only question of TV forum on that is unanswered for quite a while now. I would like to know what is the deal? Is this functionality available (as per documentation) or not (as per reality). Or is it a bug? Or maybe it's linked to program configuration?

Comment: Asking for shopping recommendations for alternatives would make your question off topic here, I would recommend removing that side of your question and potentially reposting it at [softwarerecs.se]. Bear in mind their quality guidelines: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: I don't need shopping recommendation, I need advice on working solution matching requirements as outlined.... If the only thing you took away from reading is "shopping recommendation"... Have you read the question?

Comment: Yes I have read it, and my initial though was "have you tried downloading an older version?" But then that got drowned out by "I ask for alternatives... I've tried VNC and RDP..." which sounds a lot like you are ask it for shopping recommendations. Quite frankly the last 3 paragraphs read like asking for product recommendations. If you were instead asking how to get TV to "just work" then that would be fine if someone said "it can't, but Alternative Software X does".

Comment: Ah. In a matter of speaking then, it may seem so. But it's not. I'm asking if anyone is familiar with remote access software that works. I've listed issues I have using other popular options. If that is software recommendation then I will use provided link. But maybe I'm doing something wrong. I will rewrite the question .

Comment: **Disable remote input** was used almost exclusively by technical support scammers. I am not shocked they moved that feature to a paid tier.  Scammers are not willing to pay to scam other people.  Let me clear, I am not saying you are one of those technical scammers, but TeamViewer as a company has changed their software due to them all the same

Comment: @Ramhound - That makes sense. Do you have anything to back that statement up? Not saying you make things up, just that I - and a lot of other people - would like to have something along the lines of official word from TV Team. ;) Thanks!

Comment: @AcePL I know for a fact TeamViewer took steps to block certain regions from initiating a remote connection to other parts of the world.  What those scammers then decide to do is allow you as the victim to connect to their desktop, because the block, was only one way.  They would then blank your screen out and disable your input.  What an official statement contact TeamViewer.

Comment: @Ramhound - Then it should not impact me, as I was connecting to the computers I had defined and linked to my TV account and all of them are based in UK. Thanks for info, but irrelevant to my case.

Comment: If they remove the feature for all free accounts (which is what the scammers use) then it could have affected you.  *If you are using a paid account contact TeamViewer support.*

Comment: @Ramhound - *TeamViewer took steps to block certain regions from initiating a remote connection to other parts of the world*. Doesn't sound like me. I'm on the receiving end, actually, judging from unsolicited calls I'm getting... But I understand what you're saying.

Comment: I am not saying TeamViewer actually took steps to chnage this feature, which is the reason, i suggested contacting TeamViewer

Comment: @fixer1234 - the issue is that those functions supposed to be available in TV Free. NO one asks for circumventing, no one asks (anymore) about competing product. All I want to know if it's available in free version or not. If not - fine, moving to greener pastures. If yes - what I need to do to enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by... accident.

It seems that TV just felt like limiting that option in Free version and that's. I still can't tick the boxes for both *"Disable remote input"* and *"Show black screen"* when new connection is opened.

But since I'm working in multi-display environment and TV's solution for that is to open as many connections as there are monitors, it seems that those options kick in the moment I'm opening second connection to the same remote computer.

I believe they are working after I've set up the computer I'm connecting to first, doing that locally, with all possible options turned on, like Access Control set to *"Full Control"*, *"Full access to this computer when (..) connecting to Windows Logon Screen"* ticked off in the section "Advanced settings for connection to this computer", changes in section "Advanced settings for connection to other computers" etc. And, of course, I'm connecting to logon screen and I log in using my password.

It's not just a bug with boxed ticked but the functionality still not working - my work colleague tested it for me and it really disables remote input and blanks the displays.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your question is "what is the deal?". So, I will try to answer that.

As specified in clause 2.1 of their [EULA](https://www.teamviewer.us/eula/), TeamViewer has all the rights to change the features in their product (paid or freemium). They don't necessarily have to announce those changes.

Most companies measure which features of their product are most commonly used. In order to "encourage" free users to buy their product, they might have decided to discontinue those features in the freemium version. I'm not saying that this is the case, but it is highly likely "the deal" here.

As alternative solutions for your need:

- Try a previous version which had that feature.
  However, I don't know how TeamViewer works internally. So, a previous
  version that had that feature may not work if there are some
  server-side checks on the allowed features.
- Find another brand. As suggested in the comments, [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [other popular web sites](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/) that provide this kind of service can help you to find alternatives.